# javascript function sometimes works testing with safari (client specified)

Tags: javascript, function, safari, try-catch, xmlhttprequest

I am using Safari on my mac (v7.0.2) to test a web server on a PLC, and the function pvAccess.WritePV() in the PV_Access.js is called but it executes only sometimes, which I find really strange, the error message from the if statement doesn't come up, the debugger says its working.

Also when I used the debugger on the web inspector in Safari under the develop menu, and stepped through PV_Access.js it worked every time, but if i just play it doesn't work.

I call the function:

```
<button onclick = "check_value_text_box('track')" id = "Track_home" name = "Track_home">Track</button>
```

which is:

```
function check_value_text_box(next_page)
{
    if ((!Value.value) || (Value.value.length > 4) || (Value.value > 359) || (Value.value < 0))
    {
        alert("ERROR: Please enter a number between and including 0 and 359.");
    }
    else
    {
        pvAccess.WritePV('_offset', document.getElementById('Value').value);
        window.location.href = ''+ next_page +'.asp';
    }
}
```

and pvAccess.WritePV is defined in the file PV_Access.js:

```
pvAccess =  {}
pvAccess.Func = function() 
{
    function AccessPV(name, rValue, wValue)
    {
        var url = '/goform/ReadWrite';
        var data = 'redirect=/response.asp&variable=' + escape(name);
        if(rValue != null && rValue != "")
        {
            data += '&value=' + escape(rValue);
            data += "&write=1";
        }
        else
        {
            data += '&value=none';
            data += "&read=1";
        }
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try {
            // Mozilla, Opera, Safari sowie Internet Explorer (ab v7)
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                // MS Internet Explorer (ab v6)
                xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                try {
                    // MS Internet Explorer (ab v5)
                    xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e) {
                    xmlHttp  = null;
                }
            }
        }
        if (xmlHttp) 
        {
            xmlHttp.open('POST', url , 1);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

                    if(wValue != null)
                    {
                        wValue[3] = xmlHttp.responseText;
                        wValue[3] = wValue[3].replace("<!-- B&R ASP Webserver -->",""); 
                        // value attribut of node
                        wValue.value = wValue[3];
                        return wValue;
                    }


                }
            };
            xmlHttp.send(data);
        }
    }
    // public   
    {
        this.WritePV = function(name, value) 
        {
            AccessPV(name,value);
        }

        this.ReadPV = function(name,wValue)
        {
            return  AccessPV(name, null, wValue);
        }       
    }
}
pvAccess = new pvAccess.Func();
```

When I set a breakpoint on line 55 of PV_Access.js and let it play after it breaks, it works every time. The function takes in two inputs, the name of the variable and the value to which said variable will be set to.

Comment: The `return wValue` statement in the `onreadystatechange` function indicates that the author of that code doesn't understand how asynchronous functions work. It makes no sense to return something, since there's no caller to return to.

Comment: I would guess it's because `window.location.href = ''+ next_page +'.asp';` is interrupting the `WritePV()` call before it completes.  When you go to a new page, the entire current javascript execution context is shut down.

Comment: What is the `Value` variable in `check_value_text_box`?

Comment: Are you trying to POST something and then navigate to a new page without waiting for the response?  In `check_value_text_box`, you set window.location, which will go immediately before the HTTP request has completed.  Remember it is async?

Comment: @SteveH. WritePV has no return value, it writes a variable and its value on the PLC.

Comment: @Barmar the Value is the name/id of the text area were the user inputs the variable value

Comment: @jfriend00 i just tested your theory, and you were right, the window.location is called before WritePV() is finished processing

Comment: Anyway to make sure that the window.location is called once the function finishes executing, keep in mind that this is one web page with its own check function and redirect there are others, so putting the window.location into PV_Access.js is a no.

Comment: @user3408618 - answer added with a callback so you can set window.location AFTER the ajax is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the issue appears to be caused by this line:

```
window.location.href = ''+ next_page +'.asp';
```

getting executed before your ajax call has completed, then the solution is to delay that line until the Ajax call has completed.

You can do that by adding a callback function to AccessPV so you can pass in a callback function that will be notified when the ajax operation is complete.  Then, in WritePV(), pass in a callback function and change the window.location in that callback.

```
function check_value_text_box(next_page)
{
    if ((!Value.value) || (Value.value.length > 4) || (Value.value > 359) || (Value.value < 0))
    {
        alert("ERROR: Please enter a number between and including 0 and 359.");
    }
    else
    {
        pvAccess.WritePV('_offset', document.getElementById('Value').value, function() {
            window.location.href = ''+ next_page +'.asp';
        });
    }
}

pvAccess =  {}
pvAccess.Func = function() 
{
    function AccessPV(name, rValue, wValue, fn)
    {
        var url = '/goform/ReadWrite';
        var data = 'redirect=/response.asp&variable=' + escape(name);
        if(rValue != null && rValue != "")
        {
            data += '&value=' + escape(rValue);
            data += "&write=1";
        }
        else
        {
            data += '&value=none';
            data += "&read=1";
        }
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try {
            // Mozilla, Opera, Safari sowie Internet Explorer (ab v7)
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                // MS Internet Explorer (ab v6)
                xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                try {
                    // MS Internet Explorer (ab v5)
                    xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e) {
                    xmlHttp  = null;
                }
            }
        }
        if (xmlHttp) 
        {
            xmlHttp.open('POST', url , 1);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

                    if(wValue != null)
                    {
                        wValue[3] = xmlHttp.responseText;
                        wValue[3] = wValue[3].replace("<!-- B&R ASP Webserver -->",""); 
                        // value attribut of node
                        wValue.value = wValue[3];
                        return wValue;
                    }
                    if (fn) {
                        fn(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlHttp.send(data);
        }
    }
    // public   
    {
        this.WritePV = function(name, value, callback) 
        {
            AccessPV(name,value, null, callback);
        }

        this.ReadPV = function(name,wValue)
        {
            return  AccessPV(name, null, wValue);
        }       
    }
}
pvAccess = new pvAccess.Func();
```

Comment: I have tried and now I get a 404 error. The variable data should say 'redirect=/response.asp&variable=(name of variable)&value=(value of variable)&write=1' but there is no &write=1?

Comment: @user3408618 - you'll have to figure out why that's happening since I don't have any way to execute this code.  All I intended to do was add a callback parameter to the code you posted in your question.  There's no intention to change anything related to any URL.

Comment: sorry i didn't see the if statement about the xmlHttp.responseText, it works fine now thanks for the help.